# How to disable/enable cpu cores *without* root access

Tags: linux, cpu, multicore

I have been trying to disable or enable one or more CPU cores in my linux machine using

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'n' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online"
```

Just thinking if there is a way out there to do the same but with no root access.
Thanks

Comment: May be it is not a good idea allowing to do that to non-root users.

Answer (score 2):

You can use setuid http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/12/suid-set-suid-linuxunix.html

However, setuid is disabled for security reasons for bash scripts, but you can write a program, maybe in C, that symply calls

system("echo 'n' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online");

Name the executable stopcpu, then do the following

```
chmod a+x stopcpu
sudo chown root stopcpu
sudo chmod u+s stopcpu
```

From this moment, ./stopcpu will run with root permissions without having to put root password, and this would be valid for this file only.

Comment: 2nd command requires root password though !!

Comment: but you have to run those command once. I assumed that you have root access to the machine, but you want to avoid putting the password all times. With this method you put the password once, then you will be able to call stopcpu forever without a password.
If you have no root access to the machine, I hope it is simply impossible, because if it is not true it is a very serious security issue...